# Passing parameters to Windows Service during installation

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, registry, installutil

I am creating a windows service which is suppose to look up data in a specific table and then process the record based the status.

I want to pass the DB credentials while I install the service using installutill as parameters and save them inside registry. I have tried doing so using the code bellow, but I keep getting error on the event "OnBeforeInstall".

I believe either I am passing the parameters incorrectly or I am writing code in the wrong event. Need your help to figure what am I doing wrong.

```
protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
    _eventLog.WriteEntry("OnBeforeInstall Started");
    try
    {
        RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\RyteRMS");
        if (key != null)
        {
            _eventLog.WriteEntry("Write data to registry key");
            key.SetValue("DBTYPE", this.Context.Parameters["dbtype"].ToString()); // This throws error, I am assuming as the above event entry is visible.
            key.SetValue("DATASOURCE", this.Context.Parameters["datasource"].ToString());
            key.SetValue("USERID", this.Context.Parameters["userid"].ToString());
            key.SetValue("PASSWORD", this.Context.Parameters["password"].ToString());
            key.SetValue("DBNAME", this.Context.Parameters["dbname"].ToString());
            key.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _eventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
    }
    _eventLog.WriteEntry("OnBeforeInstall Finished");
}
```

**I am writing this on the command prompt:**
installutil RMSBGService.exe /dbtype=sqlserver /datasource=hitin-lt /dbname=rms /userid=admin /password=passw0rd

**Error:** "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

P.S. I dont know how to debug the Win Service, so I am using event log to record every thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do it on my own, this is what we are suppose to do it.

```
protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    _eventLog.WriteEntry("OnBeforeInstall Started");
    try
    {
        RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\RMS");
        if (key != null)
        {
            _eventLog.WriteEntry("Write data to registry key");

            Process _prc = new Process();
            _prc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            _prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            _prc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            _prc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            _prc.Start();

            ConsoleColor _color = Console.ForegroundColor;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGreen;
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("PLEASE ENTER FOLLOWING DETAILS TO COMPLETE SETUP");
            Console.WriteLine("NOTE: if you enter wrong information, you will need to reinstall the application.");
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter DBTYPE (SQLSERVER or ORACLE):");
            key.SetValue("DBTYPE", StringCipher.Encrypt(Console.ReadLine(), "@xx"));
            Console.WriteLine("Enter DATASOURCE (SERVER NAME):");
            key.SetValue("DATASOURCE", StringCipher.Encrypt(Console.ReadLine(), "@xx"));
            Console.WriteLine("Enter DATABASE USER ID:");
            key.SetValue("USERID", StringCipher.Encrypt(Console.ReadLine(), "@xx"));
            Console.WriteLine("Enter PASSWORD:");
            key.SetValue("PASSWORD", StringCipher.Encrypt(Console.ReadLine(), "@xx"));
            Console.WriteLine("Enter DATABASE NAME:");
            key.SetValue("DBNAME", StringCipher.Encrypt(Console.ReadLine(), "@xx"));
            key.Close();
            Console.ForegroundColor = _color;
            _prc.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _eventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
    }
    _eventLog.WriteEntry("OnBeforeInstall Finished");
    base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
}
```

StringCipher is a custom function that I used to encrypt/decrypt my text. Later on start, I am reading these stored values from the registry, and decrypt them to pass it onto database connection code and do the needful.

Hope this would help someone.

**NOTE**

You must install this service using "InstallUtil", if you choose to install it using a Setup project, this installation will be stuck with a cmd window open.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,

I'll add that I'm using `ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper()` from a WPF app
to install the service, then reading the registry values from the service's c'tor.

Yes, I know it exposes API and shouldn't be used from code :-)
it's a temporary solution to enabling the installation of a service with a GUI.